# How to test setTimeout with Mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I'm doing some integration testing in my Node app and at some point in my code I call the following function:

```
async.parallel([
    function foo(callback){    
        setTimeout(function(){
            //DO SOMETHING HERE;
            callback(null, result);
        }, 500);
    },
    function bar(callback){    
       //DO SOMETHING HERE;
       callback(null, result);
    }],
function(err, results){
     //Process results here and continue
});
```

This code is part of a larger node app.

Now when I try to test my code with Mocha the test hangs because the timeout in foo() is never fired and therefore the parallel execution never finishes. When I remove the setTimeout the execution is completed just fine.

Here's the test code:

```
  it("test something", function(done) {
        request(app)
          .post(requestUrl)
          .send(testRequest)
          .expect(200)
          .end(function(err, res){
            (res.body.text).should.equal('Hello World');
            done();
          });
  });
```

**What I tried:**
Apparently, the clock is disbaled during testing so I tried using Sinon to simulate the passing of time but to no avail.

How can I solve this?

Comment: So, the `function(err, res)` callback function is not executed at all?

Comment: Yes exactly. It hangs at the setTimeout(). If I remove the timeout the code is executed just fine.

Comment: What request module are you using here?

Comment: There's gotta be something else going on here. I've tried to replicate your situation, but tests pass fine: https://gist.github.com/badsyntax/10283004

Comment: Thanks for taking the time @badsyntax. I just inserted a random setTimeout() in one of my routes just to double-check if it is ever called and again no luck. Timeouts do not fire in my code. Note: in my tests I use the timekeeper module to freeze time so I thought that that module was causing the problem so I removed it and still no luck. I cannot think of something else.

Comment: I updated my question with some more info. foo() is a function I call inside the async.parallel function.

Comment: @GeorgeEracleous Did you try using the debugger and putting a breakpoint inside the anonymous function you give to `setTimeout`? Or put a side-effect inside that function like a good old `console.log` to see whether execution ever gets there. I know you've tested but the fact is that some tests could lead to incorrect inferences. I understand that the timekeeper module could interfere with `setTimeout` but you said you've removed it and still get the same problem. So.. this is extremely bizarre.

Comment: I used the good old console.log to find out if it ever gets there and it didn't work. It was the first thing I tried. I couldn't figure it our so I simply changed my async library so I wouldn't have to use the setTimeout and now I'm ok. Still this issue is weird.

Comment: @GeorgeEracleous it would be very nice to have a dummy project that reproduces the issue so we can try it out in isolation (using the same dependencies, node.js version, and even OS if necessary).

Comment: The thing is with a dummy project it just doesn't works. But as part as a large test suite it does.

Comment: I mean, I am having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had a similar problem today.
I was using `var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers()` without `clock.restore()`.

To try that, you can use:

```
console.log(new Date().getTime());
console.log(new Date().getTime());
```

If you get twice the same value, it means that you may have change the clock.